# Ruby on Rails Payment gateway for customer based in the Philippines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm currently working on a project where my client is based in the Philippines. For Payment, I usually advice my client to use stripe although it's only available in US and Canada. For Philippines can you advice what would be my alternative in accepting Credit Card Payment?

Answer (score 1):

I would recccommend to use [Spreedly](https://spreedly.com) with a payment gateway like Paypal or [others](https://spreedly.com/gateways).